# Convert between ES6 Classes React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I am new in React-Redux. I am trying to incorporate this technology in my project, although for the moment I have not found much use, besides not liking the syntax in all the examples I see.

Here is the syntax:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import Todo from './Todo'

const TodoList = ({ todos, onTodoClick }) => (
  <ul>
    {todos.map(todo =>
      <Todo
        key={todo.id}
        {...todo}
        onClick={() => onTodoClick(todo.id)}
      />
    )}
  </ul>
)

TodoList.propTypes = {
  todos: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    completed: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }).isRequired).isRequired,
  onTodoClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default TodoList
```

How could I convert to this other syntax?:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import Todo from './Todo'

export default class TodoList extends React.Component {
constructor(todos, onTodoClick){
  super();
  this.todos = todos;
  this.onTodoClick = onTodoClick;
}

render() {
  return(
    <ul>
      {todos.map(todo =>
        <Todo
          key={todo.id}
          {...todo}
          onClick={() => onTodoClick(todo.id)}
        />
      )}
    </ul>
  );
}
}

TodoList.propTypes = {
  todos: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    completed: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }).isRequired).isRequired,
onTodoClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

Thank you all.

Comment: I don't think there is a magical stick that will convert all your classes to ES6 classes. You'll need to do it manually. You might find reading [this](http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/refactoring-react-components-to-es6-classes) and [this](http://cheng.logdown.com/posts/2015/09/29/converting-es5-react-to-es6) helpful.

Comment: Yeah. I want to do it manually. But that code I put above gives me error that 'todos' is not defined, so something I am doing wrong. I would like to know exactly how it would translate (by hand, of course) because in my code there is some error (I think in the constructor).

Comment: Your conversion won't work. It's also not equivalent; the first example is a stateless function component, which is the preferred style *when possible*.

Comment: The ctor in your example should be taking `props` like every other `Component` ctor. You need to call `super(props)` as well.

Comment: remove `this.todos` and `this.onTodoClick` from the constructor and get them from the props in the `render()` method using `const { todos, onTodoClick } = this.props`

Comment: That'd work too; the ctor is superfluous here. But most linters will complain about a component class that could be stateless and isn't. I don't really understand the issue with using an arrow function here.

Comment: Use arrow functions (stateless component) as you can. use `extends React.Component...` when you need to use the `state`, `connect()` to `redux` or life-Cycle methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* want to convert your stateless component into an ES6 class component you can just use `this.props` directly in your component.

Class components get given a special value called `props` that contains all the values given to it when it was mounted, e.g.

```
<MyComponent value={1} />
```

In this case `this.props` would look like `{ value: 1 }`.

So you can change your component to look like

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import Todo from './Todo'

export default class TodoList extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return(
      <ul>
        {this.props.todos.map(todo =>
          <Todo
            key={todo.id}
            {...todo}
            onClick={() => this.props.onTodoClick(todo.id)}
          />
        )}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

TodoList.propTypes = {
  todos: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    completed: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }).isRequired).isRequired,
  onTodoClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

In some cases, the repeated use of `this.props` may start to get a bit clunky so you can unpack props into variables, which can neaten things up a bit, like so

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import Todo from './Todo'

export default class TodoList extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { todos, onTodoClick } = props

    return(
      <ul>
        {todos.map(todo =>
          <Todo
            key={todo.id}
            {...todo}
            onClick={() => onTodoClick(todo.id)}
          />
        )}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

TodoList.propTypes = {
  todos: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    completed: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }).isRequired).isRequired,
  onTodoClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

**Side-note:** a component like this (and probably `Todo`) can benefit from extending [`PureComponent`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.purecomponent) instead of `Component` to avoid unnecessary re-renders to improve performance.

---

Using `props` in the constructor is *technically* possible

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.todos = props.todos;
  this.onTodoClick = props.onTodoClick;
}
```

or

```
constructor({ todos, onTodoClick }) {
  super(props);
  this.todos = todos;
  this.onTodoClick = onTodoClick;
}
```

and change your `render` function to look like

```
render() {
  return(
    <ul>
      {this.todos.map(todo =>
        <Todo
          key={todo.id}
          {...todo}
          onClick={() => this.onTodoClick(todo.id)}
        />
      )}
    </ul>
  );
  }
```

But I would advise against this as a common pattern to use.  The [constructor](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#constructor) is only called once before mounting the component, so any changes to the props will not result in the constructor being called again.

You can get around this by implementing [componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) and updating your variables, but this feels overly complicated for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!. It's great, just what I was looking for and it works to perfection !. With your answer, I had two doubts: - What is the difference between a function like the first (PureComponent) and the second (Component)? - Why does the first makes less renders than the second? Thanks a lot again for everything.

Comment: Just to be clear, **none** of my examples use `PureComponent`.  `PureComponent` implements [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) with a shallow compare of the `props` and `state` to see if anything has changed before calling the `render` function again.  So in this case, each `Todo` component is unlikely to actually change with subsequent renders, so making it a `PureComponent` will reduce the overall work done with each render.